# Multiply column values but exclude zero values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Im looking for way to multiply values of all columns but to exclude columns that has a value of 0. So, result should not be 0 (multiplication by 0). If there is this number of columns and rows, its easy, but what If there are 100 columns and 5000 rows?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[6,4,3,0],
                   "Col2":[1,0,0,3],
                   "Col3":[2,4,3,2]})
```

So result should look like this:

```
print(df)

# result should be multiplication of all column values, but not 0
# zeros should be excluded

6 * 1 * 2
4 * 4
3 * 3
3 * 2

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[6,4,3,0],
                   "Col2":[1,0,0,3],
                   "Col3":[2,4,3,2],
                   "Result":[12,16,9,6]})

print(df)
```

I can not change the data , so changing zeros to 1 does not work

Comment: could you just replace the 0s with 1s? That'd get the same answer

Comment: @MattR you naughty GOD.

Comment: df.replace(0, 1)

Comment: @MattR the simplicity of your solution [Insert Applause Emoji here]

Comment: @MattR Good solution, but I can not change the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply replace the 0s with 1s.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[6,4,3,0],
                   "Col2":[1,0,0,3],
                   "Col3":[2,4,3,2]})


df['Result'] = df.replace(0,1).prod(axis=1)


   Col1  Col2  Col3  Result
0     6     1     2      12
1     4     0     4      16
2     3     0     3       9
3     0     3     2       6
```

To get technical - in multiplication 1 is the [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function). In addition the identity function is 0. to *way* oversimply it - An identity function is just a fancy way of saying "return the same result by adding another variable"

To get non technical I think of the quote  "Think Smart Not Hard"

Comment: what do you mean `can't change the data`? the only way you'd change the data is by reassigning `df=df.replace(0,1)`. if you don't reassign, you can just do the calculation. See my edit. It'll get you the answer you posted

Answer (score 3):

May be just replace zero values by one and multiply values:

```py
df['Result'] = df.replace(0,1).apply(np.prod,axis=1)
```

Comment: It willn't change your initial data, because inplace=False

Comment: Can you please explain how your code works, with apply and np.prod and axis

Answer (score 2):

Simple mask `0` values to `NaN` and call `prod`

```
df['Result'] = df.where(df.ne(0)).prod(1)

Out[1748]:
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Result
0     6     1     2    12.0
1     4     0     4    16.0
2     3     0     3     9.0
3     0     3     2     6.0
```

Or mask `0` to `1`

```
df['Result'] = df.where(df.ne(0), 1).prod(1)

Out[1754]:
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Result
0     6     1     2      12
1     4     0     4      16
2     3     0     3       9
3     0     3     2       6
```

---

**step by step**:

`ne(0)` return a boolean mask where `0` is masked as `True`

```
In [1755]: df.ne(0)
Out[1755]:
    Col1   Col2  Col3  Result
0   True   True  True    True
1   True  False  True    True
2   True  False  True    True
3  False   True  True    True
```

`where` checks on each location of the boolean mask. On `True`, it keeps same value. On `False` it turns to `NaN` when there is no 2nd parameter.

```
In [1756]: df.where(df.ne(0))
Out[1756]:
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Result
0   6.0   1.0     2      12
1   4.0   NaN     4      16
2   3.0   NaN     3       9
3   NaN   3.0     2       6
```

`prod(1)` is the product along axis=1. `Prod` is defaulted to ignore `NaN`, so It returns the product of each rows without consider `NaN`

```
In [1759]: df.where(df.ne(0)).prod(1)
Out[1759]:
0    12.0
1    16.0
2     9.0
3     6.0
dtype: float64
```

When specifying the 2nd parameter for `where`, it is used to replace on `False` mask.

Comment: Can you please explain me the result with df.where and df.ne(0) and prod?

Comment: @taga: I added step by step explanation